# Why does if condition print zero value for non-zero condition?

Tags: shell

I am unable to get the required output from bash code.

I have a text file:

```
1 0.00 0.00    
2 0.00 0.00    
3 0.00 0.08    
4 0.00 0.00    
5 0.04 0.00    
6 0.00 0.00    
7 -3.00 0.00 
8 0.00 0.00
```

The required output should be only non-zero values:

```
0.08   
0.04   
-3.0
```

This is my code:

```
z=0.00
while read line
do
line_o="$line"
openx_de=`echo $line_o|awk -F' ' '{print $2,$3}'`   
IFS=' ' read -ra od <<< "$openx_de"
for i in "${od[@]}";do
if [ $i != $z ]
then
echo "openx_default_value is $i"
fi
done
done < /openx.txt
```

but it also gets the zero values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only the nonzero values from columns 2 and 3, try:

```
$ awk '$2+0!=0{print $2} $3+0!=0{print $3}' openx.txt 
0.08
0.04
-3.00
```

How it works:

`$2+0 != 0 {print $2}` tests to see if the second column is nonzero.  If it is nonzero, then the print statement is executed.

We want to do a numeric comparison between the second column, `$2`, and zero.  To tell awk to treat `$2` as a number, we first add zero to it and then we do the comparison.

The same is done for column 3.

#### Using column names

Consider this input file:

```
$ cat openx2.txt 
n  first  second
1  0.00   0.00
2  0.00   0.00
3  0.00   0.08
4  0.00   0.00
5  0.04   0.00
6  0.00   0.00
7 -3.00   0.00    8  0.00  0.00
```

To print the column name with each value found, try:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{two=$2; three=$3; next} $2+0!=0{print two,$2} $3+0!=0{print three,$3}' openx2.txt 
second 0.08
first 0.04
first -3.00
```

Comment: Thanks john.can you help in one modification.suppose input file same with the first line:"line_n first second".and i have to print non zero value with the related column name

Comment: @GovindKumar OK.  See updated answer for a method to handle column names.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{$1=""}{gsub(/0.00/,"")}NF{$1=$1;print}' file 
0.08
0.04
-3.00
```